CSS textarea Increased Line Height for newlines
When the user inputs a textarea, a line break due to wrapping looks the same as a line break due to the user entering a newline. I want the first line after a newline character to be spaced a bit further down than wrapped lines are spaced. The idea is that the user is typing paragraphs of text and they hit ENTER to start a new paragraph. It should be apparent visually where paragraphs start.
I could probably get this effect using JavaScript to replace each newline with two newlines as the user types, but I was hoping to do it with CSS.

"but I was hoping to do it with CSS" - CSS can not select based on the line break characters. Apart from a few exceptions, CSS can only select elements.

you can use <div contenteditable> to have rich text editing of some sort. Usually it's a bit tricky and not consistent across browsers. Use at your own risk.


var elem = document.querySelector(".my-textarea");
elem.focus();
.my-textarea {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.my-textarea * {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
Enter Description:
<div class="my-textarea" contenteditable></div>



